# Mongoose query to return matching elements in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Taking the following Schema, I want to find `transactions` that match a given rule and only return the matching `transactions`.

```
const dataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    client: Number,
    // ...
    transactions: [{
        value: Number
        // ...
    }]
});
```

Here is some example data:

```
{
    client: 123,
    transactions: [
        { value: 100 },
        { value: -10 },
        { value: 42 }]
}
```

Now if I'm searching for transactions for client 123 with values below 50, it should return `[{value: -10}, {value: 42}]`. Whatever I try, I can't seem to make it work. The nearest I got was with the following code.

```
Data.findOne({
    client: 123,
    'transactions.value': { $lte: 50 }
    }, 'transactions.$'
);
```

I must add that I'm not very experienced with MongoDB or mongoose. For me this seems harder than it has to be.

Comment: Filtering arrays was just covered a couple hours ago in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76517572/20042973)

Comment: What a coincidence. Can you still help me out? I tried the suggested answer you have mentioned, but I still can't make it work for my use case. The main difference is that I'm also using the `client` property as a filter parameter.

Comment: Prepend a `$match` stage ahead of the `$project` in the `.aggregate()` pipeline and put your query predicates in there. The subsequent `$project` (or `$addFields`) stage is just intended to process the array for the documents that match the overall query conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `transactions` is the only field you need from the documents (or there are only a few fields), then specifying the projection in the `findOne()` as you attempted to do so should be fine. It would look something like this:

```
Data.findOne({
  client: 123,
  "transactions.value": {
    $lte: 50
  }
},
{
  transactions: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$transactions",
      cond: {
        $lte: [
          "$$this.value",
          50
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6ORD6Gl8gcK).

If instead you wanted most/all of the fields from the document, then using the aggregation syntax (and specifically the `$addFields` stage rather than `$project`) would be simpler:

```
Data.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      client: 123,
      "transactions.value": {
        $lte: 50
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      transactions: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$transactions",
          cond: {
            $lte: [
              "$$this.value",
              50
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A09En_0ByTn)

Comment: I wish we had a general problem and answer page for `$filter` scenarios.  So many new users get hung up trying to use `$match` to filter arrays.