# Get single object by id in array inside a mongodb collection

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the below collection structure in a Mongo database:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "number"
  },
  "OfferNumber": "string",
  "ComercialCode": "string",
  "ContractNumber": null,
  "FirstDocSent": {
    "$date": "date"
  },
  "EventDate": "date",
  "EndDate": "date",
  "LastMaintenance": {
    "$date": "date"
  },
  "UserMaintenance": "rny",
  "PurgePhysicalDocDate": {
    "$date": "date"
  },
  "StoredDocuments": [
    {
      "CodeEmission": "string",
      "ItemNumber": "string",
      "DocumentType": "number",
      "DocumentNumber": "number",
      "OriginSystemCode": "rny",
      "StoreDate": {
        "$date": "date"
      },
      "IdGed": "number",
      "IdS3": "number"
    }
  ]
}]
```

StoredDocuments array contains objects representing documents that have a unique IdS3.

Based on this structure, I'm trying to implement a query in C# that selects only a single document by that IdS3, but I'm not able to filter by searching all arrays and returning only one object. So far the queries I've implemented only select the parent object.
Any implementation ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Popular topic recently. You do that sort of transformation via a projection, a related answer from yesterday is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76524531/20042973). If it's just a single entry there might be a simpler syntax discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74113511/20042973) instead

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vy_KsdxM4mM).

Note that this query seems messy but `$replaceRoot`, `newRoot` and `$arrayElemAt` is only to get the first element from the array and output it like an object.

The rest of the query is quite simple using `$match` to do a first filter and avoid to do the `$filter` in every document. And then `$filter` to get elements in the array where `IdS3` is equal to your desired number.

So using c# you can try something like this (I'm not a c# expert, but you are tagged this as `.net-driver`) provided by [MongoDB Compass export to specific language](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/export-query-to-language/):

```cs
new BsonArray
{
    new BsonDocument("$match", 
    new BsonDocument("StoredDocuments.IdS3", 1)),
    new BsonDocument("$replaceRoot", 
    new BsonDocument("newRoot", 
    new BsonDocument("$arrayElemAt", 
    new BsonArray
                {
                    new BsonDocument("$filter", 
                    new BsonDocument
                        {
                            { "input", "$StoredDocuments" }, 
                            { "cond", 
                    new BsonDocument("$eq", 
                    new BsonArray
                                {
                                    "$$this.IdS3",
                                    1
                                }) }
                        }),
                    0
                })))
}
```